# Edit RGB values of 0,0,0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, ascii, flow

I am VERY new to ArcMap and GIS in general.

I converted some lidar data to a GEOTIFF, using a program called CARIS (it was an .csar file) and imported this into ArcMap. There are some areas that are showing up as black (0,0,0).

Is there a way to modify these pixels to match the surrounding data, or interpolate them?

Ultimately, I will want to convert this over to a ASCII file to input into a Flow 3D program. (I will probably be asking future questions about that too!)

Am I on the right path?

Or is there an easier way to go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach [Changing a color-mapped raster layer to use the RGB renderer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/changing-a-colormaped-raster-layer-to-use-the-rgb-renderer.htm)

If your raster has a color map, it is displayed with the Colormap rendered by default. You can change this to use the RGB renderer.

- Click the Add Data button Add Data to add a raster to ArcMap.
- Click Windows on the Main menu to view the Image Analysis window, and click * * Image Analysis.
- Click the raster layer in the Image Analysis window.
- Click the Colormap to RGB button Colormap To RGB in the Processing section of the window.
- This adds a temporary raster dataset layer to the table of contents.

Comment: It does not allow me to select that button. Does that mean I am not able to modify it?[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXQqE.jpg

Comment: That is possible, make sure you don't have a lock on the image file.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this effect because LiDAR doesn't like water, it acts like a mirror, in the centre of a run (flight) the intensity is very high but just outside centre the pulse is reflected away (angle of incidence = angle of reflection) and does not return to the sensor and therefore records *no return*. You can interpolate with a [terrain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005v00000002000000), provided you have 3d analyst extension available or with a [LAS dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//015w00000057000000) (basic license requires 3d or spatial analyst).

Interpolating will close in gaps between valid records - ALL gaps up to a boundary called a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), even over the land. You could make a terrain or LAS dataset from all your records restricted to [ASPRS class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/lidar-point-classification.htm) 2, 8 and 9 (Ground, Model Key and Water), convert to raster and then Extract by Attributes to restrict to elevations below your intended area.

To import your LAS for a terrain use [LAS to MultiPoint](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000009m000000) which is far more efficient than creating single points for each pulse/return. (3d analyst required)

To export a terrain to a raster you will need 3d analyst regardless of license level, use the tool [Terrain to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000002t000000). Linear interpolation method is faster but can look blocky, Natural Neighbors is slower but creates a smoother raster.

To export a LiDAR (LAS) dataset to raster use the [LAS Dataset to Raster tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000052000000) which will offer more interpolation methods but as you want to fill in the blanks stick with Natural Neighbors or Linear fill method.

If you are on a basic license with no 3d or spatial analyst extension you can look at [LASTools](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/) as a viable alternative, there's a GUI available in QGIS. Licensing isn't too expensive and the tools are efficient; Or contact your local Esri representative to obtain extension(s) or upgrade your license.